# Logon Rule based on time

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

Is there any way to control when users can login in a site or not?
Example: I have a bunch of FBA users that can only login in the site from monday to friday, each day from 6am to 7pm.

Comment: You can inject a JavaScript on MasterPage, on Page load check if the timing is correct, if not redirect them to custom page displaying the message..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Write a custom http module for this requirement . Since it runs on each and every page, before you land make a check of the current time .*